# SQL statement to get the correct category without digits

Tags: mysql

i have a column category which has the following data:

```
0100 Single Function Inkjet Printers
0100 Wireless Phones
400 optics (421)
4000 sound and recording (267)
80000 electrical & heating (60)
81000 plumbing
Accessories
Action Figures/Collectibles
```

I am trying to create a category calculated field in SQL which will have only the text:

```
Single Function Inkjet Printers
Wireless Phones
optics
sound and recording
electrical & heating 
plumbing
Accessories
Action Figures/Collectibles
```

I have tried using a combination of left, right, trim and substring functions to do so, but havent been successfull. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is mysql version?

Comment: i am using mysql 8.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MySQL 8.0 or higher this can be done using regex_replace:

```
ALTER TABLE data
ADD COLUMN calc_val varchar(50)
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(val, '[(]?[0-9]+[)]?', '')));
```

This example replaces numbers with optional round brackets, if you have any other number formats that needs to be replaced - see the regex manual.

Demo:
https://dbfiddle.uk/d8Aapd5j

Comment: If a substring to be removed is posessed in the middle then multiple spaces will be obtained.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  raw VARCHAR(255),
  cleaned VARCHAR(255) AS (TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(raw, '\\(?\\d+\\)? *', '')))
);
INSERT INTO test (raw) VALUES 
('0100 Single Function Inkjet Printers'),
('0100 Wireless Phones'),
('400 optics (421)'),
('4000 sound and recording (267)'),
('80000 electrical & heating (60)'),
('81000 plumbing'),
('Accessories'),
('Action Figures/Collectibles');
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| raw | cleaned |
| --- | --- |
| 0100 Single Function Inkjet Printers | Single Function Inkjet Printers |
| 0100 Wireless Phones | Wireless Phones |
| 400 optics (421) | optics |
| 4000 sound and recording (267) | sound and recording |
| 80000 electrical & heating (60) | electrical & heating |
| 81000 plumbing | plumbing |
| Accessories | Accessories |
| Action Figures/Collectibles | Action Figures/Collectibles |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/myTU59UA)

`TRIM()` provides leading space removing when the substring to be deleted is a prefix.